# Symfony2 - OVH- errors 500

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, ovh

I try to put my Symfony project on my OVH hosts.
I have modified the .htaccess, but I have this error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, postmaster@www.triath-swim.fr
>   and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

The log of my site:

```
40.77.167.32 triath-swim.fr - [04/Dec/2016:01:54:05 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 545 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
40.77.167.32 triath-swim.fr - [04/Dec/2016:02:51:12 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 545 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
104.131.164.180 triath-swim.fr - [04/Dec/2016:03:54:31 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 347 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; spbot/5.0.3; +http://OpenLinkProfiler.org/bot )"
104.131.164.180 www.triath-swim.fr - [04/Dec/2016:03:54:31 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 351 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; spbot/5.0.3; +http://OpenLinkProfiler.org/bot )"
104.131.164.180 www.triath-swim.fr - [04/Dec/2016:03:54:36 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 351 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; spbot/5.0.3; +http://OpenLinkProfiler.org/bot )"
151.80.33.137 triath-swim.fr - [04/Dec/2016:18:16:39 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 347 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.1 Safari/602.2.14"
```

The website is accessible here: www.triath-swim.fr

Comment: So have you checked the error log as it is suggested?

Comment: You should determine the actual error by finding it in the logs, there is no other way of proceeding with this as the error can be caused by just about anything.

Comment: I looked at the symfony logs, there is nothing

Comment: Check the error log of your webserver.

Comment: If you're serving with apache2, try looking at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: I thought logs will help me find the error, but no I do not know where my error came from. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @MathieuPerdrieau give us the log output and we might give you an idea or two what went wrong (what you posted looks like `apache2` access.log)